# Horizontal centering with \subfloat

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats

Please how to horizontally center-justify the following array of figures with the `subfig` package ?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
    \subfloat[From $n=0$ to $n=-1$]{\label{fig:a}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_a_reverse.eps}
    }                
  \qquad\qquad\qquad
    \subfloat[From $n=-1$ to $n=0$]{\label{fig:aa}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_a.eps}
  } \\
    \subfloat[From $n=-1$ to $n=-2$]{\label{fig:b}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_b_reverse.eps}
    }                
  \qquad\qquad\qquad
    \subfloat[From $n=-2$ to $n=-1$]{\label{fig:bb}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_b.eps}
  }
  \\
    \subfloat[From $n=-2$ to $n=-3$]{\label{fig:c}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_c_reverse.eps}
    }                
  \qquad\qquad\qquad
    \subfloat[From $n=-3$ to $n=-2$]{\label{fig:cc}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_c.eps}
  }    
  \caption{Random walk on the Pascal pyramid}
  \label{fig:bratelli}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As a general note, providing driver options to `graphicx`, like the `dvips` in your case, is no longer required and also not recommended. Modern LaTeX versions don't have an issue detecting the correct driver themselves and stating a wrong driver will cause problems.

Comment: Have a look at the `adjustbox` package, especially the `center` key, i.e. `\begin{adjustbox}{center=<value>} .. \end{adjustbox}`. Here a value of about `.5\textwidth-5mm` should be right. I will post a full answer later when I have more time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to work a bit harder. The following set of macros sets each subfloat in a zero width box, so adding filling space will do.

1. The `\csubfloat` macro has the same syntax as `\subfloat`; beware, though, that images should not fill the whole line.
2. The `\centerhfill` macro has an optional argument, default `\quad` to add a space in the center. If it's not enough, you can experiment with `\centerhfill[\qquad]`.

In the example I have used the `demo` option to `graphicx`; don't use it yourself, but don't add `dvips` either.

The `\fakeig` macro is just for producing the test and you don't need it; just remove the lines and uncomment the `\includegraphics` ones.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newcommand{\csubfloat}[2][]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\subfloat[#1]{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\centerhfill}[1][\quad]{\hspace{\stretch{0.5}}#1\hspace{\stretch{0.5}}}

% This is for the example
\newcommand{\fakeig}[2]{\includegraphics[width=#1,height=#2]{foo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \csubfloat[From $n=0$ to $n=-1$]{\label{fig:a}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_a_reverse.eps}%
    \fakeig{2cm}{2cm}%
  }\centerhfill
  \csubfloat[From $n=-1$ to $n=0$]{\label{fig:aa}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_a.eps}%
    \fakeig{2cm}{2cm}%
  }\hspace*{\fill}

  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \csubfloat[From $n=-1$ to $n=-2$]{\label{fig:b}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_b_reverse.eps}%
    \fakeig{3cm}{3cm}%
  }\centerhfill
  \csubfloat[From $n=-2$ to $n=-1$]{\label{fig:bb}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_b.eps}%
    \fakeig{3cm}{3cm}%
  }\hspace*{\fill}

  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \csubfloat[From $n=-2$ to $n=-3$]{\label{fig:c}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_c_reverse.eps}%
    \fakeig{4cm}{4cm}%
  }\centerhfill
  \csubfloat[From $n=-3$ to $n=-2$]{\label{fig:cc}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_c.eps}%
    \fakeig{4cm}{4cm}%
  }\hspace*{\fill}

  \caption{Random walk on the Pascal pyramid}
  \label{fig:bratelli}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note a generous usage of `%` to mask end-of-lines that act like spaces, which are not wanted.

[image]

Another option would be to include each `\subfloat` in a `minipage` as wide as half the `\textwidth`, but you have less control about the center spacing; this could be modified using a fraction of `\textwidth`, say `\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}` or similar.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

% This is for the example
\newcommand{\fakeig}[2]{\includegraphics[width=#1,height=#2]{foo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \subfloat[From $n=0$ to $n=-1$]{\label{fig:a}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_a_reverse.eps}%
    \fakeig{2cm}{2cm}%
  }
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \subfloat[From $n=-1$ to $n=0$]{\label{fig:aa}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_a.eps}%
    \fakeig{2cm}{2cm}%
  }
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \subfloat[From $n=-1$ to $n=-2$]{\label{fig:b}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_b_reverse.eps}%
    \fakeig{3cm}{3cm}%
  }
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \subfloat[From $n=-2$ to $n=-1$]{\label{fig:bb}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_b.eps}%
    \fakeig{3cm}{3cm}%
  }
  \end{minipage}

  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \subfloat[From $n=-2$ to $n=-3$]{\label{fig:c}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_c_reverse.eps}%
    \fakeig{4cm}{4cm}%
  }
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \subfloat[From $n=-3$ to $n=-2$]{\label{fig:cc}%
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_c.eps}%
    \fakeig{4cm}{4cm}%
  }
  \end{minipage}

  \caption{Random walk on the Pascal pyramid}
  \label{fig:bratelli}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great work! Though Mico's solution is easier, I accept yours because it only uses the `subfig` package.

Comment: Looks like a good case for the `center` key of `adjustbox` to me.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Are you referring to the definition of `\csubfloat`? I don't want the box to have a width.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the `subfig` package and its `\subfloat macro`, you may want to use the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment. Specifically, you could specify six `subfigure` environments of a given fixed width of, say, `0.4\textwidth` and use `\centering` instructions within each of these environments.

Not having access to your image files, it's not possible to guarantee that the following code will work without a need for further tweaking. In particular, you may need to change the widths of the `subfigure` environments to accommodate the graphs in the third row of subfigures.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subfigure' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_a_reverse.eps}
       \caption{From $n=0$ to $n=-1$}\label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}          
    \qquad\qquad\qquad  % spacing between the subfigures
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}  
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_a.eps}
       \caption{From $n=-1$ to $n=0$}\label{fig:aa}
    \end{subfigure}    

    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_b_reverse.eps}
       \caption{From $n=-1$ to $n=-2$}\label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}          
    \qquad\qquad\qquad  % spacing between the subfigures
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}  
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_b.eps}
       \caption{From $n=-2$ to $n=-1$}\label{fig:bb}
    \end{subfigure}    

    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_c_reverse.eps}
       \caption{From $n=-2$ to $n=-3$}\label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}          
    \qquad\qquad\qquad  % spacing between the subfigures
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}  
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/IncludePyramid_c.eps}
       \caption{From $n=-3$ to $n=-2$}\label{fig:cc}
    \end{subfigure}    

\caption{Random walk on the Pascal pyramid} \label{fig:bratelli}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent. Moreover the caption widths are very nice.